# g++ on MinGW can't keep line number information when using SDL2

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw, sdl-2

In MinGW but not Unix, gdb doesn't have line number information when the program uses (or even #include's) SDL2. The MCVE is simple indeed:

```
#include "SDL.h" //<--comment this out and we get line numbers in gdb again

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    return 0;
}
```

This is the Makefile:

```
INCLUDE_FLAGS   :=  -I../../external/SDL2-MinGW/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2  

LIBRARIES       := mingw32 SDL2main SDL2                
LIB_FLAGS       := $(foreach library,$(LIBRARIES),    -l$(library))
LIB_DIR_FLAGS   := -L../../external/SDL2-MinGW/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib

ALL_FLAGS       := $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(LIB_FLAGS) $(LIB_DIR_FLAGS)

a.exe: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -g -o a.exe main.cpp $(ALL_FLAGS)
```

This is how I call gdb:

```
PATH="../../external/SDL2-MinGW/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/bin:$PATH"
gdb a.exe
```

I'm running the latest on MinGW (mingw-gcc-bin, mingw-gcc-g++-bin are 9.2.0-1; mingw-gdb-bin is 7.6.1-1).

What's the fix here? I don't suppose SDL2 was compiled with -g, but that shouldn't matter to main.

Edit: output is shown here.

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from C:\Users\briggs_w\Desktop\cpp-for-lazy-programmers-master\ch29\mcve\a.exe...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x404270
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\briggs_w\Desktop\cpp-for-lazy-programmers-master\ch29\mcve/a.exe
[New Thread 8652.0x700]
[New Thread 8652.0xab8]
[New Thread 8652.0x36f0]
[New Thread 8652.0x244c]

Breakpoint 1, 0x00404270 in main ()
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
0x00401
```

Comment: How do you test that? Show what output you have and what you expect it to be.

Comment: I test it with the script shown in the problem above, the one that says PATH="..." and gdb a.exe.

I have now added the output from gdb.

Comment: @TopologicalSort there is no problem here, it just isn't your main, but rather the one implemented in `SDL2main`. `#include <SDL.h>` eventually includes `SDL_main.h`, which have `#define main SDL_main` (on some target platforms). So your main is actually `SDL_main` now, that's all there is.

Comment: @Keltar: yep, that's it. If you'll post this as an answer and add the fix, which is: break SDL_main not break main, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

SDL2 have `SDL2main` library to handle entry point on different target platforms. E.g. on unix systems you have `main` entry point, on windows - sometimes `main`, sometimes `WinMain`, and on e.g. android or ios things can be very different. SDL lets you pretend entry point is always `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, but it needs to inject its own actual entry point before that. To do that it uses `#define main SDL_main`, effectively renaming your `main` to `SDL_main`, then calling that after initialisation phase. So, in your case, breaking on `main` debugger can't show you line numbers because `SDL2main` built without debuging symbols; your code still does have symbols so breaking anywhere in your code will have all expected things.

As a side note, because you use C++ and not C: `main` absolutely have to be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. C++ (or any C) allows much more freedom with main declaration, but once its name isn't `main` anymore - compiler no longer knows it have any special meaning and will produce C++ mangling and usual overloading capabilities. It may result in unexpected linking errors.

You can drop `SDL2main` if you implement entry point yourself and notify SDL you don't want that - by using `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before including `SDL.h` and calling `SDL_SetMainReady` before any other SDL function. In that case you don't need to link with `SDL2main` but you'll lose its extra features like utf8 command line arguments.

Comment: keltar, thanks. Can you add that the fix here is to break SDL_main instead of break main? People finding this will need that clarification I think.